# How to take Spring batch job parameters and pass to sql

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I need to implement the extraction of 9 reports via spring batch jobs, i.e. done. But I stuck in between.I have to pass job parameters to spring job, and passing that parameter to SQL in order to generate different report. 
What concept should I use here? Any leads or help are appreciated.

For ex job will accept 2 parameters: ABC and xyz

These 2 param will be used inside the SQL of reader in order to generate different report.

Answer (score 1):

Consider posting more info, such as some relevant sections of your code, for better feedback.

However, in general, one approach is to use [Job scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#job-scope) to access `jobParameters` from a configuration bean, such as this example:

```
@JobScope
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader flatFileItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[input]}") String 
name) {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Foo>()
                        .name("flatFileItemReader")
                        .resource(new FileSystemResource(name))
                        ...
}
```

Comment: @J Woodchuck I'm very new to spring batch

Comment: Can you please elaborate via spring batch xml

Comment: Here is an xml example with job parameter for a sql query: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/iosample/jdbcPaging.xml#L30